# call inline function and pass in current item as the argument - Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Im trying to create a loop of items like this...

```
    for each (var btn:Object in ViewButtonData)
    {
      // build element
      var box:HBox = new HBox();
      box.styleName = "lefttab";
      box.width = "100%";
      box.addEventListener("rollOver", HoverTab(btn.id, 1));
      box.addEventListener("rollOut", HoverTab(btn.id, 0));

      // add element to list
    }
```

I would like to pass in current HBox to the 'HoverTab' function.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HBox should automatically be available in the event handler via event.currentTarget.

Answer (score 4):

James Ward's comment is correct. You can just do:

```
function myHandler(event:Event):void {
    var myHBox:HBox = event.currentTarget as HBox;
}
```

That said, the answer to your question is:

```
box.addEventListener("rollOver", function(e:Event) { HoverTab(box, btn.id, 1); });
```

..spread out for more readability:

```
box.addEventListener("rollOver", 
                     function(e:Event) { 
                         HoverTab(box, btn.id, 1); 
                     }
                    );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
box.addEventListener("rollOver", hoverTab(btn.id, 1));
box.addEventListener("rollOut", hoverTab(btn.id, 0));
```

This won't work unless `hoverTab` is a function that returns a function that takes an event as its sole argument. Replace it with:

```
box.addEventListener("rollOver", hoverTab);
box.addEventListener("rollOut", rollOutTab);
```

And as James mentioned, you'll get `HBox` from `event.currentTarget`

```
function hoverTab(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   var box:HBox = HBox(event.currentTarget);
}
```

To get `btn.id` inside `hoverTab`, store HBoxes and btn.ids into two arrays from the for-each loop. Now you can get the index of `HBox` using `indexOf` method - `btn.id` will be at the same index in its array.

```
var boxes:Array = [];
var ids:Array = [];
for each (var btn:Object in ViewButtonData)
{
  // build element
  var box:HBox = new HBox();
  boxes.push(box);
  ids.push(btn.id);
  box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, hoverTab);
  box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, rollOutTab);

  // add element to list
}
function hoverTab(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   var box:HBox = HBox(event.currentTarget);
   var btnid:Number = ids[boxes.indexOf(box)];
}
```

Alternatively, (since ActionScript allows different types in the same array), you can push them into the same array and read the `btn.id` as `array[array.indexOf(box) + 1]`